# Dev-C++ Creating EXE For Wrong Version of Windows?

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I have started using Dev-c++ lately (previously VC++ 2012 but just wanted to try it out), I really like it but I am having a problem. Everything was working fine, but now whenever I compile and link a project into a final exe and run it I get an error telling me that this exe is not for my version of Windows (32 bit). Here is the exact message in case anyone wants to know specifically:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

I have a 32 bit PC, and my Dev-C++ settings are set to compile to that (TDM-GCC 4.7.1 32-bit Release). Also it is not my code itself causing this error, I am not new to C/C++ itself. I have tried multiple times and everything that is causing this error in Dev-C++ works fine when compiled with VC++ 2012. If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it. I even reinstalled Dev-C++ to try to solve this, with no prevail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. Switching the compiler to ming from the TDM-GCC fixed the issue.